# What permissions to allow access to GetDashboardEmbedUrlCommand method for Amazon Quicksight?

Tags: amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

For Amazon Quicksight,  what permissions do we need to assign to a specific user to allow access to the GetDashboardEmbedUrlCommand method in their SDK?

I am trying to allow Quicksight Dashboard access to a programmatic user, but it seems the permissions I've assigned are incorrect.
However, it seems that there are no permissions other than the read permissions that I have already enabled on the programmatic user, as it says here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonquicksight.html

In the section for GetDashboardEmbedUrl, it say I only need read permissions.

So I'm a little stuck on what permissions are needed in the SDK.

Comment: depending on how you are creating and authenticating your users, you might need `ds:` permissions; quicksight does use the aws directory services , at least for quicksight managed users